# Anti-concentration of a non-negative RV

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable. Show that for $\theta \in [0,1]$:

$$P(X\geq \theta E[X]) \geq (1-\theta)^2\frac{E[X]^2}{E[X^2]}$$

**What I've tried:**

Try to upper bound $(1-\theta)E[X]$ then rearrange to get the desired lower bound.

By linearity of expectation:
$$(1-\theta)E[X] \leq E [1\{X\geq \theta E[X]\}(X-\theta E[X])]$$
Then we can apply Jensen's inequality:
$$\leq E[1\{X\geq \theta E[X]\}(X-\theta E[X])^2]^{1/2}$$
So then
$$E[1\{X\geq \theta E[X]\}(X-\theta E[X])^2]\geq (1-\theta)^2E[X]^2$$

But then how do I show the following?

$$E[1\{X\geq \theta E[X]\}(X-\theta E[X])^2] \leq P(X\geq \theta E[X])E[(X-\theta E[X])^2]]$$

After which we would have:
$E[(X-\theta E[X])^2]] \leq E[X^2]$ and rearranging yields the desired result.

Comment: See [Payley Zygmund Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality)

Comment: Thanks, looks like cauchy schwarz.